# AWS SimpleDB CLI: How to use the 'select' command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'm trying to use the `select` command of AWS SimpleDB from AWS CLI.

The required call is as follows:

  `select
--select-expression <value>`

with `select-expression` being described as follows: `--select-expression (string) The expression used to query the domain.`

[The select is supposed to be similar to the `SQL` select statement](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingSelect.html), however I keep getting errors about the syntax, e.g.:

`aws sdb select --select-expression "select * from my-domain"`

`An error occurred (InvalidQueryExpression) when calling the Select operation: The specified query expression syntax is not valid.`

I can't find any documentation or example about the right syntax to use, either.

Comment: Side-note: Amazon SimpleDB is effectively deprecated. It's still there, it's still running, the [documentation is available if you know where to look](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html). However, if you are looking for a long-term solution, consider using Amazon DynamoDB instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution - turns out I needed to use single quotes for the query and special character around the table name:

> aws sdb select --select-expression 'select * from `my-domain`'